# NET::SSH2 with sudo

Tags: linux, perl, ssh

I'm trying to run various commands with net:ssh2 however the commands need to be run as root. I have root logins disabled over SSH and I have keys setup, so I can ssh and use 'sudo su - root' to get root access without a password. The problem is that I need to run multiple commands so I was wondering if it's possible to connect, then sudo to root, then run all the commands I need without having to pipe an echo to sudo or use expect.

The relevant section of my code I'm working with is the following, I'd preferably like to 
sudo before the exec($commands[0]) if possible.

EDIT: I can't login directly to root with or without a password as it's against policy unfortunately. I have to connect with my user first.

```
    my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
    $ssh2->connect($server) or die "$!\n";
    if ($ssh2->auth_publickey($user,"/home/$user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", "/home/$user/.ssh/id_rsa"))
    {
            my $chan = $ssh2->channel();
            $chan->blocking(1);
            $chan->exec($commands[0]);
            my @users;
            while(<$chan>) {push(@users,$_);}
            my $stdout=join("",@users);
            print $stdout;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't try this, but `su` has the `-c` argument, which passes a single command to the shell to execute, and then finishes the shell. This most likely corresponds to the `-c` argument of your shell, which in fact happily accepts compound commands here, e.g. a list of commands separated by `;`.

Thus executing

```
sudo su -c 'command1 ; command2 ; command3 ' - root
```

could work here. (Or even only one of those commands, and then repeatedly call these.)

(But I think there might be something wrong with the settings if they allow a passwordless `sudo su - root`, but not normal `sudo` command executing.)

Comment: Thanks! This should work perfectly. The reason we can only use 'sudo su -' is because it's restricted in the sudoers file. I didn't setup all the rules so I can't say why exactly it was done, here's what the sudoers file looks like:  %ourgroup       ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - root

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `sudo su -` just proceed each command with `sudo`. If you are allowed to sudo without a password it should work just fine:

```
$chan->exec("sudo $commands[0]");
```

If your command needs root's path just specify the full path to it. (Can't tell since you aren't showing what the command is.)

Comment: I would do that, but sudo by itself requires a password. I'd have to do something like 'echo "command" | sudo su - root' and while that does work, I feel like it's really an ugly way to do things but I will do it as a last resort if there's no other way

Comment: @zoite: I'm no sysadmin, but that sounds like a really weird way to set up sudo rights.

Comment: sudo can be changed to allow a user to switch without a password. If you have to input a password at some point you'll have to use Expect.

Comment: Another (and probably the better way to do it IMHO) is to give your user permission to the commands or files in question.

Comment: @Cfreak I don't need to use a password if I sudo to the root user, I only need a password if I issue a command as sudo other than changing users. Unfortunately I can't change the permissions around as there are thousands of clients on the server

Comment: @zoite: requiring password for everything but `sudo su -` doesn't make sense from a security standpoint. Just allow your user to run anything as root via sudo or even enable remote root logins (with your current policy, having it disabled is mostly useless).